# Are airliners designed to land safely with no undercarriage deployed?

Tags: aircraft-design, landing, airliner, emergency

Complete undercarriage failure ("belly landing") is very rare in large passenger aircraft, but [not unprecedented.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UC8ySY_GlUk)

[image: 767 Belly Landing]
([source](https://theflyingengineer.com/out-of-the-blue/lot-767-gear-up-landing/))

I would imagine it would be fairly easy to predict which part of the fuselage and engines would be in contact with the runway in such a situation. Are airliner fuselages and / or engines designed for this eventuality, so that the event is more likely to be survivable? Or is it considered too rare for structural modifications to be cost-effective?

Comment: Note: planes are designed to safely "land on water", which requires a similar design. And IIRC modern aircraft must have detachable engines (in case of heavy contact to the ground). And aircraft are designed for evacuation of passengers. (for sure not only a soft landing with fire on lavatory)